# Image downloader not downloading files

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**ANSWERED THANKS FOR THE HELP**

My code seems to be working, but I'm not able to find why it's not downloading anything.
my folder stays empty here is my code
https://pastebin.com/nA1JmUuu
I am typing this as this is the way to run the code

```
py image_downloader.py -n 5 -s "red roses" -d "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Coding\Image Searcher For Gifting\downloads"
```

Comment: Add snippet of `image_downloader.py` so that your problem could be reproducible.

Comment: I have please check the hyperlink

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nA1JmUuu

Comment: In your `download_images_to_dir` function definition, you have to pass `image_type` as an optional argument with default value being `jpg`, as you are using it. You can also avoid `extension = image_type if image_type else 'jpg'` in `save_image` function then and use `image_type` directly.

Comment: Did it worked? Adding `image_type` as an argument.

Comment: How can I make image_type have jpg as default

Comment: `def fun(a, b=0)` , here `b` has default value of 0 in the function while `a` is a required argument. Similarly, you can just add `image_type='jpg'` in your function parameters to set it as an optional argument.

Comment: It didn't work. :(

Comment: def download_images_to_dir(images, save_directory, num_images, image_type = "jpg"):
    for i, (url, image_type) in enumerate(images):
        try:
            logger.info("Making request (%d/%d): %s", i, num_images, url)
            raw_image = get_raw_image(url)
            save_image(raw_image, image_type, save_directory)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)

Comment: @Tawstar Please add that code to your question.

Comment: the code is there please check the hyperlink